# Ввод данных с задержкой между знаками в selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

Столкнулся с проблемой . Нужно взять данные с файла и ввести их на сайте с задержкой между знаками (имитация ввода с клавиатуры)

```
string[] file_name = File.ReadAllLines("../FILE/data.txt");
string field1 = file_name[0];
IWebElement credentials_Search = BotSelenium.FindElement(By.Id("username"));
foreach (var item in field1.ToCharArray())
        {
            credentials_Search.SendKeys(field1);
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
        }
```

Такой код не работает(( все равно вводит всю строку с интервалом в 1.5 сек .

Comment: credentials_Search.SendKeys(field1); Вы на каждую букву вводите всю строку. Нужно credentials_Search.SendKeys(item);

Comment: метод `.SendKeys` принимает только string . не работает ни `item.ToString` ни `(string)item`

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался . Метод `.SendKeys` принимает только стринг .

```
foreach (var item in field1.ToCharArray())
{
     credentials_Search.SendKeys(item);
     Thread.Sleep(1500);
}
```